# преобразовать вложенный массив javascript в формат csv

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! никогда не обращался тут за помощью, но помучавшись сутки над этой жестокой задачки, все же был вынужден отписаться тут.

Мой код проходит почти все проверки, за исключением одного теста, в котором проверяется выброс исключения при передачи в функцию некорректных данных.

вот мой код:

```
function arrayToCsv(data) {
  const separator = ",";
  let csv = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      let value = String(data[i][j]);
      if (value.includes(separator) || value.includes('"') || value.includes("\n") || value.includes("\r")) {
        value = `"${value.replace(/"/g, '""')}"`;
      }
      csv += value;
      if (j !== data[i].length - 1) {
        csv += separator;
      }
      if (typeof data[i][j] === "function") {
        throw new Error("Unexpected value");
      }
    }
    if (i !== data.length - 1) {
      csv += "\n";
    }
  }

  return csv;
}
```

тут условие:

> Нужно написать функцию, которая переводит двумерный массив (массив массивов) в CSV формат и возвращать строку О формате: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV (детали в разделе "Спецификация")

Допустимые значения в качестве элементов массива - числа и строки Если встречается функция - выбрасывать ошибку с текстом "Unexpected value"

Функция принимает: data - массив массивов, содержашие числа или строки

Функция возвращает: Строку в формате CSV

Пример:

```
arraysToCsv([[1, 2], ['a', 'b']]) /* '1,2
a,b'
*/
arraysToCsv([[1, 2], ['a,b', 'c,d']]) /* '1,2
"a,b","c,d"'
*/
```

а тут логи тестов :

```
Ваш ответ не прошел тест!
FAIL test.js
  csvGenerator тест
    ✓ работает в простом случае и аргументах по-умолчанию (4ms)
    ✓ корректно экранирует запятые (1ms)
    ✓ корректно экранирует кавычки
    ✕ выбрасывает ошибку при некорректных данных (4ms)

  ● csvGenerator тест › выбрасывает ошибку при некорректных данных

    expect(received).toThrow(expected)

    Expected message: "Unexpected value"

    Received function did not throw

      79 |     ];
      80 |     for (const data of incorrectDatas) {
    > 81 |       expect(() => arrayToCsv(data)).toThrow(new Error('Unexpected value'));
         |                                      ^
      82 |     }
      83 |   });
      84 | });

      at Object.toThrow test.js:81:38)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 3 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.035s
Ran all test suites matching /\/777F523C029F1FE5DFAE1C0D99ADF731\i.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend-tasks@1.0.0 test:task: `jest "test.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend-tasks@1.0.0 test:task script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     2023-07-14T17_04_41_629Z-debug.log
```

буду признателен если кто поможет

Comment: Можете в вопрос добавить значения из incorrectDatas, которые подаются для теста?

Comment: уникальность тестировщика в том , что эти данные нигде явно не указываются))) приходится тупо отгадывать, но я полагаю что на вход дают обычную функцию в качестве элемента массива, я хз, может с тестировщиком что-то не так, но в вс коде при проверке этого же кода строка с throw new Error также не срабатывает, попробовал записать этот фрагмент в теле try catch, в вс коде все сработало а вот тест все равно не проходит

Comment: Попробуйте добавить перед вторым for `if (typeof data[i] === "function") { throw new Error("Unexpected value"); }`. И я бы еще проверял входные данные. Что data это массив, что каждый элемент data[i] тоже массив, если что не так, выкидывал бы ошибку

Comment: попробовал, результат все тот же(( может тестировщик сломался?

Comment: Я у себя локально запустил, ошибка генерится. Однако, не зная, какие данные идут на вход, сложно сказать, что у вас с кодом не так.

Comment: после второго for добавил if (typeof data[i][j] !== "string") {
        throw new Error("Unexpected value");
      } и теперь уже ошибка генерируется, но не проходят проверку первые два теста

Comment: Есть открыты URL, куда можно загрузить эту функцию на проверку?

Comment: нет, такого нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вашу функцию с другими проверками:
Проверяем, что входящая **data** это массив. Далее, что **data[i]** тоже массив и **data[i][j]** это строка или число

```js
function arrayToCsv(data) {
  if (!Array.isArray(data)) throw new Error("Unexpected value");
  const separator = ",";
  let csv = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!Array.isArray(data[i])) throw new Error("Unexpected value");
    for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      if (typeof data[i][j] !== "string" && typeof data[i][j] !== "number") throw new Error("Unexpected value");
      let value = String(data[i][j]);
      if (value.includes(separator) || value.includes('"') || value.includes("\n") || value.includes("\r")) {
        value = `"${value.replace(/"/g, '""')}"`;
      }
      csv += value;
      if (j !== data[i].length - 1) {
        csv += separator;
      }
    }
    if (i !== data.length - 1) {
      csv += "\n";
    }
  }

  return csv;
}

const vals = [
  [[() => 1+1]],
  [() => 1+1],
  'dsfsd',
  12,
  () => 1+2,
  [12, '2632'],
  [['() => 1 + 3']]
];

vals.forEach(item => {
  try {
    console.log(item, arrayToCsv(item));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(item, e.message)
  }
})
```

Comment: да вы просто гений ))) и это сработало, и как я сам до этого не додумался, видимо за весь день что я просидел над задачкой мозг уже перестал функционировать как надо )) спасибо)

Comment: @Seriy если ответ вас устраивает, отметьте его галочкой слева. Если нравится, можете даже проголосовать )

Comment: галочкой уже отметил, по причине того, что я тут новенький эти отметки в общей дискусиии не отображаются, а проголосовать, обязательно))

Comment: @Seriy Галочка - принять ответ слева от ответа, серая. Ниже кнопок вверх вниз )